# MessageComposeViewController only presents once

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm using Xcode 8 to build an application for iPhone.
My simple app has an button. When user tap on this button, `messageComposeViewController` is called and with phone number and message content filled.
The message went through successfully when I clicked on Send button.
The problem is `MessageComposeViewController` is showing only once.
After the message sent, when I tapped on the button to call it, a black screen showed up instead of the message composer.
My code is attached below. 
I appreciate any help.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate   {

    let msg = MFMessageComposeViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var coordinate_label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        self.msg.body = "Message Content"
        self.msg.recipients = ["xxx-xxx-xxxx"]
        self.msg.messageComposeDelegate = self

        self.present(msg, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller:   MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
        switch result.rawValue {
            case MessageComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            case MessageComposeResult.failed.rawValue:
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            case MessageComposeResult.sent.rawValue:
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            default:
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your task is done with mine code then approve my answer . thank you

Answer (score 4):

**Try this code**

```
import Foundation
import MessageUI

let textMessageRecipients = ["1-800-867-5309"] // for pre-populating the recipients list (optional, depending on your needs)

class MessageComposer: NSObject, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    // A wrapper function to indicate whether or not a text message can be sent from the user's device
    func canSendText() -> Bool {
        return MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
    }

    // Configures and returns a MFMessageComposeViewController instance
    func configuredMessageComposeViewController() -> MFMessageComposeViewController {
        let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self  //  Make sure to set this property to self, so that the controller can be dismissed!
        messageComposeVC.recipients = textMessageRecipients
        messageComposeVC.body = "Hey friend - Just sending a text message in-app using Swift!"
        return messageComposeVC
    }

    // MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate callback - dismisses the view controller when the user is finished with it
    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Note, latest syntax 2017 ..

```
func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**In Your viewController ..**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Create a MessageComposer
    let messageComposer = MessageComposer()

    @IBAction func sendTextMessageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        // Make sure the device can send text messages
        if (messageComposer.canSendText()) {
            // Obtain a configured MFMessageComposeViewController
            let messageComposeVC = messageComposer.configuredMessageComposeViewController()

            // Present the configured MFMessageComposeViewController instance
            // Note that the dismissal of the VC will be handled by the messageComposer instance,
            // since it implements the appropriate delegate call-back
            presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // Let the user know if his/her device isn't able to send text messages
            let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Cannot Send Text Message", message: "Your device is not able to send text messages.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            errorAlert.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Himanshu. thanks, I just edited in the latest Swift syntax (feel free to unwind, edit etc as usual)

Comment: I got error `Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT.` also `didFinishWith` is not called